# Foreach for MySQL (In Trigger)

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to create validate if that NEW.`Some Field` = ' ' (THAT IS NOT NULL JUST EMPTY INPUT) then text messange is "[table:person] - `Some Field` column is not valid", and i using this method now:

```
BEGIN
IF NEW.`Some Field1` = '' THEN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45000'
  SET MESSAGE_TEXT = '[table:person] - `Some Field` column is not valid';
END IF;
IF NEW.`Some Field1` = '' THEN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45000'
  SET MESSAGE_TEXT = '[table:person] - `Some Field` column is not valid';
END IF;
END;
```

and this method we cant do if too many validate, I still do not understand with NEW.`Some Field`, is it like an array in php and other prog. languages

and if same, can we use a method like in HP, I give an example:

```
$new = array('some1'=>'TEST','some2'=>'');
foreach($new as $field => $val){
   if($val == ''){
     echo "[table:person] - `{$field}` column is not valid";
     //and final we can use continue or return false
   }
}
//And that result is "[table:person] - `some2` column is not valid"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

> Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger. OLD and NEW are MySQL extensions to triggers; they are not case sensitive.
>   In an INSERT trigger, only NEW.col_name can be used; there is no old row. In a DELETE trigger, only OLD.col_name can be used; there is no new row. In an UPDATE trigger, you can use OLD.col_name to refer to the columns of a row before it is updated and NEW.col_name to refer to the columns of the row after it is updated.
>   A column named with OLD is read only

Comment: thanks for response, and... how to get simple syntax now?